# Как настроить доступ к GitLab по SSH под WSL?

Tags: windows, ssh, gitlab, wsl

Если я помещаю SSH-ключи в директорию `C:\Users\User\.ssh\`,
то, пытаясь получить доступ к GitLab из Linux-консоли (WSL),

```bsh
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

я получаю следующий ответ:

> **Permission denied (publickey).**

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSL видит `C:\Users\User\.ssh\` как `/mnt/c/Users/User/.ssh/`, а своей корневой папкой `~` он считает `/home/user/`.

Эта проблема может быть решена следующим образом:

1. Копируем закрытый [SSH-ключ](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#rsa-keys-and-openssh-from-versions-65-to-78) (названный, например `gitlab_com_rsa`) в папку `C:\Users\User\.ssh\`
2. Добавляем в файл `C:\Users\User\.ssh\config` [запись о ключе для gitlab.com](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/#working-with-non-default-ssh-key-pair-paths):

```
# GitLab.com
Host gitlab.com
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_com_rsa
```

3. Linux-консоль Windows (WSL) использует отдельную директорию `~/`, куда нужно скопировать папку `.ssh/`:

```bsh
cp -R /mnt/c/Users/User/.ssh ~/
sudo chmod -R 700 ~/.ssh
```

4. Тестируем доступ к gitlab.com с помощью следующей команды:

```bsh
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

---

P.S.

Символические ссылки не позволяют изменить уровень доступа к ним,
поэтому у меня не получилось использовать их для решения этой задачи:

```bsh
ln -s /mnt/c/Users/User/.ssh/ ~/.ssh
sudo chmod 700 -R ./.ssh
stat -c %a ~/.ssh
```

> 777

```bsh
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

> Bad owner or permissions on /home/user/.ssh/config